# Is there any way to work with Audiotoolbox while receiving phone calls in iphone

Tags: objective-c, audiotoolbox

Is there anyway to turn - on speakers from our iphone application while receiving the phone call so that user can continue the conversation through the out speaker , will our iphone application work while receiving phone calls

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

no there is not you cant do that

Comment: Okay Thanks, but there are some applications where we can save the phone call conversations so how does that work ?

Comment: hey pal am new to iphone development just asked to know whether its possible thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: I tried to be definitive, sorry if it came off wrong, the iOS sdk does not allow you to record peoples phone calls.